# Subclassing a Java class in JRuby, with Generics information

Tags: ruby, generics, jruby, akka

I'm trying to create an actor, using the newest Akka version (2.3.2 right now) using JRuby. Problem is, I keep getting the error:

```
Java::JavaLang::IllegalArgumentException: erased Creator types are unsupported, use Props.create(actorClass, creator) instead
```

Basically, I'm following the code here on [Akka Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/java/untyped-actors.html#creating-actors)

I cannot create a `akka.japi.Creator`, because this requires Generic information, and these are erased at run-time (and JRuby is basically a run-time-everywhere). What I already tried:

```
class GreetingActor < UntypedActor
  def onReceive(message)
    if (message.is_a? Greeting)
      puts("Hello " + message.who)
    end
  end
end

system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem")
greeter = system.actorOf(Props.create(GreetingActor))
```

The last line fails with `erased Creator types are unsupported`. I tried to wrap it under a `akka.japi.Creator`, but with the same error (as Creator needs generics information, and JRuby doesn't provide it). I've tried to use "become_java!" on GreetingActor, but it returns nil (JRuby can't create new java classes from Ruby classes if the Ruby class extends from a Java class).

Is there a way to declare the Creator passing generics information?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing and while I don't have an answer to the title's question I do have an answer for getting the example working. You have to use a different means of constructing the Props instance.

You need to use a factory:

```
java_import 'akka.actor.UntypedActorFactory'

class GreetingActorFactory
  include UntypedActorFactory
  def create
    GreetingActor.new
  end
end
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
system = ActorSystem.create("GreetingSystem")
props = Props.create(GreetingActorFactory.new)
greeter = system.actorOf(props, "greeter")
greeter.tell(Greeting.new("John Weathers"), nil)
```

Hopefully, this helps you get further along!

Comment: Yes, I've already solved this Akka case with the code in this GIST: https://gist.github.com/mauricioszabo/6a713fd416c512e49f70

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved the Akka problem using the following gist: https://gist.github.com/mauricioszabo/6a713fd416c512e49f70

Still, the JRuby implementation may fail on other libraries that depends on not-erased types, but for now, I can work around in Akka using the code above.